# PYTHON: Finding the average of values of a nested list

Tags: python, list, average, mean

I have a list:

```
    data=[ [["apple",2]], [["cake",5],["cake",8]], [["chocolate",3],["chocolate",9],["chocolate",10]],[["grapes",6]] ]
```

This list (data) consists of lists (data[x]), which consists of lists (data[x][x]) containing the same word together, each with a number with it. I want to find the average of the number for each word (any floats rounded to integer).

For example, there are 2 cakes in the list (data[1]) and in the same list are the numbers 5 and 8. I want the average out of those two numbers, which would be 7, and so data[1] would be changed to ["cake",7]

If this is done for each element in the list, the result should be:

```
    data=[["apple",2],["cake",7],["chocolate",7],["grapes",6]]
```

How could this be done? Thanks :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` within a list comprehension:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> [[set(i).pop(),round(sum(j)/len(j),0)] for i,j in [zip(*i) for i in data]]
[['apple', 2.0], ['cake', 7.0], ['chocolate', 7.0], ['grapes', 6.0]]
```

The `zip` function here would separate your values from names in nested lists:

```
>>> [zip(*i) for i in data]
[[('apple',), (2,)], [('cake', 'cake'), (5, 8)], [('chocolate', 'chocolate', 'chocolate'), (3, 9, 10)], [('grapes',), (6,)]]
```

Then you can loop over them and calculate the avg and use `set` to select the set of names!also note that is have used `round` function as you wanted the avg for the `cake` to be `7` as its 6.5 .the round function will do the job for you

Comment: Thank you very much (and for answering yesterday's question as well). However I am only familiar with for loops in the format: 
`for i in x:
    #code...`
How does it work if you use "for" in the way you did there? Where you had `[list] for x,y in [list]`

Comment: You're welcome ;) as you can see the result of `[zip(*i) for i in data]` contain lists with 2 element so `for i,j in` will assign the first element to `i` and the second to `j`.

Comment: Oh no... `numpy.mean` did not work in my code. I imported `numpy` but it came up with a syntax error, highlighting `numpy.mean`'s `numpy` red. What should I do? If `numpy.mean` is not going to work, what is an alternative?

And thank you for answering my above question :)

Comment: nope, I think the problem is with my python recognising `numpy` as a module. :(

Comment: the error is anything with `numpy` that I do. So for example, if I did `import numpy` to get the `numpy` module, and did something like `numpy.mean(x)` the word `numpy` would be highlighted red as a syntax error.

Comment: @MikasaAckerman i think this is another problem you can ask it as  a new question!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
x=[ [["apple",2]], [["cake",5],["cake",8]], [["chocolate",3],["chocolate",9],["chocolate",10]],[["grapes",6]] ]
y=[]
for i in x:
    avg=0
    c=0
    for k in i:
        avg=k[1]+avg
        c=c+1
    avg=avg/c
    y.append([k[0],avg])
    avg=0
    c=0

print y
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 2], ['cake', 6], ['chocolate', 7], ['grapes', 6]]
```

Comment: Huh! vks, when did ya start answering non-regex?

Comment: @BhargavRao QA Automation Python :P.......still learning..........dont have the level of expertise you have.........just looping and stuff.........

Comment: Student at PESIT, B'lore 2nd yr. From which place in India are you?

Comment: Thanks! ... If I visit Pune, I'll stop at your place for tea! ... [You??](https://plus.google.com/109138161220331168798/posts)

Comment: @BhargavRao nah rarely i use it :P......... vksingh1512@gmail.com and on  fb as well by this id :)

Comment: I have any regex doubts, I'll mail directly

Comment: @BhargavRao sure!!!! drop me a test mail :P..........doubts regarding python will come ur way :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with 2 list comprehensions and [`numpy.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) function or [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) function if you use python 3:

```
In [1]: [[x[0][0], round(np.mean([y[1] for y in x]))] for x in data]
Out[1]: [['apple', 2.0], ['cake', 7.0], ['chocolate', 7.0], ['grapes', 6.0]]
```

If you don't have mean function, you can calculate it like this

```
In [2]: tmp = ([x[0][0], [y[1] for y in x]] for x in data)
In [3]: [[x[0], round(sum(x[1])*1.0/len(x[1]))] for x in tmp]
Out[3]: [['apple', 2.0], ['cake', 7.0], ['chocolate', 7.0], ['grapes', 6.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Any possible ways for the `round()` function to return for example `2` instead of `2.0`?

Comment: yes, you can use `int` as a function instead of `round`